# Creating Custom Metadata from Test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, json, custom-metadata

I am trying to create custom metadata from Apex test class. I have used this solved question as a reference and tried to create the same. But when I try to run the test method, I see the error as:

> System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of
>   List/Set

**This is what I tried in my code:**

```
 Mxx_hhhh.customMeta  = (List< Custom_Metadata__mdt>) JSON.deserialize({"Program_Id__c":"16"}, List< Custom_Metadata__mdt>.class );
```

Please let me know if there is any issue in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling `JSON.deserialize` that the JSON is a list of objects (`List< Custom_Metadata__mdt>`) but the JSON string you are suppying represents only a single object.

The JSON for a list containing a single object is e.g.:

```
'[{"Program_Id__c":"16"}]'
```

This [json.org](http://json.org/) page explains the syntax of JSON - there is not a lot to it so its worth getting familiar with it.